# Как распарсить в laravel request через foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, request

уважаемые программисты).

В request есть многомерный массив, как его правильно распарсить через **foreach** в blade (HTML)

[image: многомерный массив из request]

если не складывать все массивы в массив js_schedule - то получилось так:

```
@foreach( old('js_day_from') as $key => $value)

<select name="js_day_from[{{$key}}]">
     @foreach($lg_day_week as $k => $v)
              <option value="{{$k}}"
               {{old('js_day_from.'.$key) == $k ? 'selected' : ''}}
               >{{$v}}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
@endforeach
```

Что я только не пробовал!!! пришлось сделать так, а хотелось бы в один все сложить аккуратно!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach(request()->get('js_shedule') as $shedule)
<select name="{{$shedule->day_from}}">
     @foreach($lg_day_week as $k => $v)
              <option value="{{$k}}"
               {{old('js_day_from.'.$shedule->day_from) == $k ? 'selected' : ''}}
               >{{$v}}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Пока что вот так. Что такое `$lg_day_week` ?

Comment: $lg_day_week = array (
    1 => 'пн',
    2 => 'вт',
    3 => 'ср',
    4 => 'чт',
    5 => 'пт',
    6 => 'сб',
    7 => 'вс',);

Спасибо проверим)